# Denomination of bills using c++ modulus operator

Tags: c++, modulus, operation

Please help me! It seems there's an error in my c++ program. The code shows wrong output about denominations, Given as input an integer amount in pesos. Write a program that will display the number of 1000, 500, 100, 50, 20 and 10 peso bills. Output as well the remaining amount after all denominations have been removed.

And this is my program code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter the amount: ";
    cin  >> a;

    cout << "No. of 1000 peso bills:  "  << a/1000;
    cout << "\nNo. of 500  peso bills:  "  << a%1000/500;
    cout << "\nNo. of 100  peso bills:  "  << a%500/100;
    cout << "\nNo. of 50   peso bills:  "  << a%100/50;
    cout << "\nNo. of 20   peso bills:  "  << a%50/20;
    cout << "\nNo. of 10   peso bills:  "  << a%20/10;
    cout << "\n\nThe rest of the amount: " << a%10;
}
```

The output shows:

```
Enter the amount: 34757
No. of 1000 peso bills:  34
No. of 500  peso bills:  1
No. of 100  peso bills:  2
No. of 50   peso bills:  1
No. of 20   peso bills:  0
No. of 10   peso bills:  1

The rest of the amount: 7

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.156 s
Press any key to continue.
```

The number of 10 peso bill must be 0 instead of 1, How can I suppose to correct this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Figure out how to solve a simpler example, e.g. `a == 50`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the math. Since 50 is not a multiple of 20, you need to fix the calculation for the 10 pesos bills:

```
(a%50-(a%50)/20*20)/10;
```

This is of course only a solution for this specific case. In general, if you have other bills, things are more complicated. In your case you just got lucky because most bills are an exact multiple of *all* smaller bills, where the 50/20-pair is the only exception.

---

A more general and readable solution, inspired by the other answer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter the amount: ";
    cin  >> a;

    cout << "No. of 1000 peso bills:  "  << a/1000;
    cout << "\nNo. of 500  peso bills:  "  << (a%=1000)/500;
    cout << "\nNo. of 100  peso bills:  "  << (a%=500)/100;
    cout << "\nNo. of 50   peso bills:  "  << (a%=100)/50;
    cout << "\nNo. of 20   peso bills:  "  << (a%=50)/20;
    cout << "\nNo. of 10   peso bills:  "  << (a%=20)/10;
    cout << "\n\nThe rest of the amount: " << a%10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix the problem is dropping the amount that you have already represented with larger bills from the total, like this:

```
cout << "No. of 1000 peso bills:  "  << a/1000;
a %= 1000;
cout << "\nNo. of 500  peso bills:  "  << a%1000/500;
a %= 500;
cout << "\nNo. of 100  peso bills:  "  << a%500/100;
a %= 100;
cout << "\nNo. of 50   peso bills:  "  << a%100/50;
a %= 50;
cout << "\nNo. of 20   peso bills:  "  << a%50/20;
a %= 20;
cout << "\nNo. of 10   peso bills:  "  << a%20/10;
a %= 10;
cout << "\n\nThe rest of the amount: " << a;
```

This would model the process of making change by removing the amounts for which you have already provided larger bills from consideration when you get to smaller bills.

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/MtFNfI).

Comment: +1 For a more general solution, I added a simplified version of it to my answer.